# Regex pattern for alphanumeric and - and ()

Tags: java, regex

Hi I want a Regex Pattern for alphanumeric values and it should also allow `-` and `()` characters.

I tried  this pattern but its not working for me

```
[a-zA-Z0-9](\-\(\))*
```

Comment: What does your attempt at Java code look like? Or are you expecting someone to write it for you?

Comment: what you have tried??

Comment: [a-zA-Z0-9](\-\(\))*

Answer (score 3):

Your pattern must look like `[a-zA-Z0-9()\-]*`

Comment: You don't need to escape the dash: Dashes appearing first or last in a character class are *literal* dashes (not range operators).